# How to disable caching the variable value passed in the success block

Tags: java, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, gwt

Friends,

I am calling an AsyncCallback function and the variable in the success method is caching the value. I doesn not want that varibale cache the value. How can I do that.

My code is given below:

```
 Service.getGroup(abc.getText(), source, , new AsyncCallback<Long>() {
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        do something
                     }
                    public void onSuccess(Long result) {
This result varibale is caching the value. 
}
```

Steps I have done for testing.

1. Once control comes in the sucess block I change the result value by hand in the debugger mode. After than that whatever value I pass I see the same value what I have set at the time of debugging even after I refreh the page.

Comment: It is unclear what this code is supposed to do or what the problem is. The code is a) not Java and b) nonsensical - for example checking a `Long` if it is a `Long`.

Comment: This is a java GWT code. I just want to ask that what can I do so that the result variable does not cache any value

Comment: I know it's GWT - and I also know it doesn't cache values. I strongly suspect the problem is with your server side.

Comment: From server side I am getting different value but when the control comes to the  success block and when I inspect the value of result variable, everytime I get the same value what I have set from changing the varible value in debug mode in eclipse.

Comment: It is not clear at all. Your last sentence (steps you have done for testing) is complete nonsensical. Please expand (edit the question text) step by step: "I change the result value" Is that the code?, by hand in the debugger?, in the form? "Whatever value I pass" You mean from the form to the server? the server to the client? Can you not see you are not helping with your explanation?

Comment: Perdi , I have edited my question text as per your suggestion.

Comment: What GWT version are you using? Do you run `Super Development Mode` or `Classic Development Mode`?

Comment: GWT version is 2.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If debugger somehow caches the variable, that's a debugger issue. I'd try running it in normal mode (add a test Label in the form to display your result for testing).